# Why don't my stock purchases go through?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I'm doing the assassination missions and playing the stock market. I have around 180 million at the moment. The problem I'm having goes roughly like this:

1. I pick a stock on the market and enter the 'buy' page.
2. I press on the '+' button until it's at the max amount of shares.
3. I press 'buy'.
4. On the next page, I click 'confirm'.
5. On the page after that, I click 'continue'.
6. I am shown my portfolio page; my portfolio is empty and no money has been removed from my account.

This has happened for several different stocks, so it's not related to one particular company. I tried breaking up my purchases into smaller chunks and that worked. So I'm thinking maybe there's a maximum $ value for each transaction, or a maximum number of total stock per transaction. Anyone know what's causing this issue? Is it just a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes when you hold down the + button it goes over the max amount you can afford, usually by 1 share. Once you get to the max remove a few shares and it usually works. Had the problem when I was trying to do the assassination missions.

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me too. Just buy 1 share first and the it’ll be in your portfolio, after that buy as many shares as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, only I intentionally drove a stock price down to maximize the profit per share. Based on my experience, and yours, it doesn't appear to be the $ value of the stock, but a max number of shares per transaction. I also tried breaking them up into two transactions and it worked just fine. My problems started around the $70 million mark.

Answer (score -1):

Turn autosave off.. I had the same issue